# Interested Challenge: Is it possible to make a class according to a given prototype?

Tags: mongodb, typescript

Say: there is already a given schema definition object:

```
const schema = { prop1: { type: String, maxLength: 8 }, prop2... };
```

Is it possible that: without declare the interface for each schema object, make a respective class which can produce documents with `prop1:string, prop2...` extracted from the schema.

I expect something like this in my app:

```
// schema definition:
const PersonSchema = { name: { type: String, maxLength: 8 } };

// class factory
const PersonClass = SchemaClassFactory(PersonSchema);

// instance with props defined in schema.
let person1 = new PersonClass();
person1.name = 'Jack'; 
let person2 = new PersonClass();
person2.name = 3; // should be wrong hinted by tslint.
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why would you want to declare a class differently than a standard class?

Comment: The schema definition object will be exported to another 3rd party module which uses it to verify the insert data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class for the schema object using a mapped type and conditional types to extract the shape of the object from the schema.

A possible solution is below, I am not sure I covered all the ways you can defined the schema in mongoose, but this should get you stared:

```
const PersonSchema = { 
    name: { type: String, maxLength: 8 },
    age: { type: Number },
    title: String,
    id: ObjectID
};

type PrimitiveConstructor<T> = {
    new (...a: any[]): any; 
    (...a: any[]): T
}

type Constructor<T> = {
    new (...a: any[]): T; 
}
type ExtractType<T> = {
    [P in keyof T] : 
        T[P] extends PrimitiveConstructor<infer U>? U :
        T[P] extends { type: PrimitiveConstructor<infer U> } ? U:
        T[P] extends Constructor<infer U> ? U :
        T[P] extends { type: Constructor<infer U> } ? U:
        never
}
function createClass<T>(schema: T): new (data?: Partial<ExtractType<T>>) => ExtractType<T> {
    // The class will not have the fields explicitly defined since we don't know them but that is fine 
    return new class {
        // Optional constructor for assigning data to the fields, you can remove this if not needed
        constructor(data?: any){
            if(data) {
                Object.assign(this, data);
            }
        }
    } as any;
}


var PersonClass = createClass(PersonSchema);
type PersonClass = InstanceType<typeof PersonClass>

let p = new PersonClass();
p.name ="";
p.name = 2; // error
p.id = new ObjectID(10);
let p2 = new PersonClass({
    name: "",
});
```

Comment: You are epic! Really.

Comment: @DC 10x, I do have the epic badge, going for the legendary badge now ;-)

Comment: There is 2 more type:  one is array like [String], [Foo]...  the other is enum like [1,4,'a'].

Comment: @DC I'll add casses for those.... On my phone since I just left on holiday so it may take me a while :-)